# Do we want accepted answers to be unpinned on Joomla Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[Stack Overflow changed the way they sort answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/2943403):

> We no longer pin the accepted answer (with the green checkmark) to the top of the list of answers. By default, we now sort strictly by votes (descending order by highest score), and the accepted answer's order in the list is based on its score.

and it is asked on Meta Stack Exchange if [we would like to have the accepted answer unpinned on our site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/352329):

> We can change the way the engine sorts answers in site settings. We would like to hear from you all if it is something you want to see on your site. ... We are going to collect feedback before the end of September 19th.

If Joomla Stack Exchange is going to unpin accepted answers, we must gather indications of support on this Meta page.  Please voice and vote your opinion concerning what is best for our community.

Answer (score 2):

## YES

Unpinning the accepted answer allows better content to potentially occupy the top ranked position.  This is beneficial when newer/later answers are posted which are superior to older/earlier answers with the green tick.

Also, because the asker may not be the best judge of which answer is "best", unpinning gives the community the power to democratically rank page content in a way that will best serve researchers.

Comment: I vote yes because that makes sense to me although it might be better for StackExchange to implement this choice as a profile option so individuals can choose how they want to view SE websites.

Answer (score 0):

## NO

The way that the system currently favours accepted answers is appropriate.

The asker should wield ultimate, unilateral, permanent power over whether a specific answer should be stuck in the top position on the page, even if the community votes in greater favour of a non-accepted answer.